# Is it possible change all the dimensions of an image using cv2?

Tags: python, opencv

I have an image that when I read the shape of, it comes out like this:

```
data = cv2.imread("myimg.png")
data.shape
(145, 145, 3)
```

I want to change the third element which is `3` to `30`. SO the final shape should look like this: `(145, 145, 30)`  I wonder if its possible and what would it do the image.

Thanks.

Comment: The third element in the tuple returned by `data.shape` is the number of color channels that the image has. What are you trying to accomplish by changing the shape of the data?

Comment: I am using a pretrained keras model that accepts images in that shape and I cannot manufacture any image with 30 channels. So, I wonder if it possible for any sort of conversion.

Comment: Which model are you using ?

Comment: Its a deep CNN model with multiple Convo3D and Convo2D layers. I mean its nothing provided by keras but by a few researchers.

Comment: I don't think you'll have to convert a single image to (145, 145, 30), it won't make any sense. What I think is you might have to convert this image into grayscale i.e. (145,145,1) and combine 30 images of same shape with it and feed it into CNN.

Comment: Makes total sense of what you are saying. Any heads up on how to combine 30 images into one?